What does it mean is there the flat square on top of another flat Square
I get notifications with a 3D mimicking icon that looks like a simple Square stacked on top of another simple Square

Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. As of written, it's unclear without seeing how the icon really looks like. If this is a notification icon, then the linked question should help you in identifying it.
